# How to run a servie and send a broadcast to a Activity when it is finished?

Tags: android

I have a service that i retrieve 7 URL's.

Oncei retrieve the URLs from the service, i want to send a broadcast with the URL stored as an extra. i want to   send a broadcast when the images are finished downloading to the main activity to refresh my BaseAdapter. My Service will be the one to send the broadcasts and my  Activity will be the one with the receiver.

The problem is i am downloading the Strings from a server. The MainActivity needs these before it starts.

What could i do to by time while the service downloads the Strings?

Also i thought about running tha downloading of the Strings in my main activity in an asynctask but  i only want the Strings to be checked and downloaded once a week.

Is my solution the best? Could some one give me an example of how i would implement this. I am familiar with broadcast recievers. just dont know how i would use it for this particular project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate a BroadcastReceiver inside your activity's onCreate() method and register the receiver inside the activity's onStart() method.
Ensure that you unregister the receiver in the activities onPause() or onStop() methods. 
Register the receiver again in onResume().

For more details take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: Iam familiar with broadcast receivers. I was hoping some one could provide an example of what i need to do. Could you do?

Comment: For example how would i instaniate the broadcast receiver from the activity? Do the following stated in my question above?

Comment: Cant give you full code right now...but here are a couple of snippets..

private BroadcastReceiver receiver;
onCreate(Bundle x)
{
           receiver =new BroadcastReceiver()
  {
   
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
   {
    // do something here
    
   }
  };
}

onStart()
{

registerReceiver(receiver,someIntentFilter);

//Do other stuff here
}

onPause()
{
unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

onRestart()
{

registerReceiver(receiver,someIntentFilter);

}

Comment: sorry the moment i press enter it saves the edits to took soem time to do it. :P  the formatting is bad...so copy it to notepad and look at it

Comment: You dont need to put it in the manifest. You can register the listener inside the activity itself. You just have to ensure that the listener is unregistered and registered again as the activity moves through its lifecycle.

Comment: Okay so how do i send the broadcast to it?

Comment: use the sendBroadCast() method on Context

Comment: From the service corrext? Got it.Thanks. Do you think this is the best way for me to do this?

Comment: Try it out. It seems a little complicated for what you want to accomplish, which I'm guessing is to synchronize a list every week. If it works fine, I suppose it is ok. You could just do it in an Asycntask on your activity. Check the last time such an update was done, and if its been more than a week, then run the asynctask and get the update. If this stuff works for you (I haven't tested it...written off the top of my head) then please accept the answer. Happy coding!